# No overload for <Method> matches delegate 'System.Threading.WaitCallback

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

I am beginner in dot net. While converting VB.Net code to C#, I encountered a problem. Here is my VB.Net code...

```
Imports System.Threading

Dim waitCallInitialize As New WaitCallback(AddressOf ServiceInitialize)

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(waitCallInitialize)

Private Shared Sub ServiceInitialize()        

  WebServiceClient.CreateCalendarService()

  WebServiceClient.CreateClaimsService()

End Sub
```

And my Equivalent c# code is..

```
using System.Threading;


WaitCallback waitCallInitialize = new WaitCallback(ServiceInitialize);

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(waitCallInitialize);


private static  void  ServiceInitialize()
     {
         WebServiceClient.CreateCalendarService();
         WebServiceClient.CreateClaimsService();

     }
```

But this gives me the error:

> "No overload for 'ServiceInitialize' matches delegate 'System.Threading.WaitCallback'

Can someone provide a solution for this and the reason for the error?

Comment: Your question is just like all the other questions asking about the same error message and the answer is the same: your method's signature must match the delegate signature. See marked duplicate for the earliest such example.

Answer (score 1):

[WaitCallback Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) expects object state. ServiceInitialize must be:

```
private static  void  ServiceInitialize(object state)
     {
         WebServiceClient.CreateCalendarService();
         WebServiceClient.CreateClaimsService();

     }
```

Comment: Thank you....Its working..But it was working fine in my Vb.Net code without parameter 'Object state' in 'ServiceInitialize'. What the difference in c# and Vb.Net in this case??

Comment: You're welcome. I don't have big experience with VB.NET, so I have no idea why it works. But, [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx) have only 2 overloads. Each of them expects WaitCallback and WaitCallback Delegate expects object arg

Comment: @vivekvijayakumar: please read the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531336.aspx. It has the answer to your question about why VB.NET works in this example.